# Sonar false positive, "change condition so that it does not always evaluate to true."

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-analysis, sonarlint

Sonar is raising "changes this condition so that it does not always evaluate to true" for below code. I have consulted multiple people they all agree it is a false positive are we missing something?

```
public SearchResponse getSearchResponse(SearchRequest searchRequest) {
    try {
        searchRequest.validate();
    } catch(VerifyException e) {
        ///some code to make errorResp
        return errorResp
    } catch(Exception e) {
        String key = searchRequest != null ? serchReqeust.getKey() : null;
        Logger.log("some text {}", key);
        //some code to make errorResp
        return errorResp;
    }
}
```

The error is raised in generic catch block at `searchRequest != null`.
However if searchRequest is null, first line in try block will throw NullPointerException and if I don't check for null in my catch block it will break again in my catch block. Making my method fail again which is what I don't want.

Edit:

As some people in comments asked for code to reproduce the error i have uploaded it to github at https://github.com/shariqislam786/test the issue is reproducible with sonar lint 3.4 in eclipse as well.

Comment: Perhaps do an `if (searchRequest != null) {` before the `try` so that you know that `searchRequest` is good? Does Sonar assume that the only possible other exception is a `NullpointerException`?

Comment: Also see this [Why shouldn't a method throw multiple types of checked exceptions?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/263874/why-shouldnt-a-method-throw-multiple-types-of-checked-exceptions)

Comment: What's your version of SonarJava? You can find this in _Administration > Marketplace_.

Comment: `key != null ? key : null` == `key`.

Comment: Is there anything in the `//some code to make errorResp` which would imply that it can't be null? E.g. invoking a method on it?

Comment: Could provide a code snippet which is self-contained, reproducing the issue systematically? In the current form, too much information is missing to reproduce it in SonarLint.

Comment: @AndyTurner actually its the first line of try which sonar tells me implies that searchRequest cannot be null in the exception block.

Comment: @AndyTurner (key != null ? key : null == key) agreed i just wrote something quickly to demonstrate the problem so i ended up writing it removed in edit.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam the version is 5.6.6

Comment: @Michael-SonarSourceTeam i have uploaded the test code to https://github.com/shariqislam786/test the issue is reproducable in eclipse with sonarlint 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbolic execution engine from the SonarJava analyzer (5.1.1) is raising an issue because it assumes that the only way to reach the `catch` block would be by at least have `searchRequest` being non-`null`. This is a limitation of the engine, which is not covering these case for the moment. The following ticket tracks this limitation: [SONARJAVA-2669](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2669)

Now, as you said it, nothing prevent you to call the method with the parameter being `null`. In such case, the `NullPointerException` will be thrown and, indeed, we will reach the `catch (Exception e)` block with `searchRequest` being `null`.

SonarJava is consequently raising a **False Positive**.

Now, regarding your implementation choice, I believe that handling the `null`-case like this (by relying on thrown exception) is not something that people usually expect. An explicit `null`-check when entering the method are usually way clearer and should be preferred.

Note that as a good practice, I think that it would be clearer to annotate the `searchRequest` parameter of the method with `@javax.annotation.Nullable` or some similar *nullness* annotation (this one is from [JSR-305](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/)). This will help other developers (and the SonarJava engine) to understand in which state you can provide parameters, and make it crystal clear.

Comment: Would it be possible to disable this specific error? I don't want to disable entire rule.

Comment: Without reworking large parts of the engine, unfortunately not. I would encourage your to *close the issue as 'False Positive'*